# Openerp report designer call function from parser

Tags: report, odoo, designer

I created a report to my object by open office openerp report designer extension,

[image]
on my report i need to call the function process, so i need to attach a parser to my report to get my function.

i defined a parser:

[image]

how can i attach my parser to the report i creayed, i need my report to be .odt file

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please add the following line at the end of your parser.

report_sxw.report_sxw(
    'your.report.name',
    'your.openerp.model.like.product.product', 
    'addons/your_module/report/rml_file_name.rml',
    parser=notariat_report_contrat,header="external"
)

Thats it. parser is attached with your report.